# Delete second row of header in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in PANDAS which has two lines of headers.How could I remove the second line? For example, I have the following:

```
         AA  BB  CC  DD
         A   B   C   D
Index    
   1     1   2   3   4
   2     5   6   7   8
   3     9   1   2   3
```

and I would like to get something like this:

```
         AA  BB  CC  DD
Index    
   1     1   2   3   4
   2     5   6   7   8
   3     9   1   2   3
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) with `-1`: last level:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(-1)
print df
       AA  BB  CC  DD
Index                
1       1   2   3   4
2       5   6   7   8
3       9   1   2   3
```

Or specify second level: `1`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)
print df
       AA  BB  CC  DD
Index                
1       1   2   3   4
2       5   6   7   8
3       9   1   2   3
```

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!